# jquery .before() if class isn't present

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Using pagination, I have a div structure like so in the first page:

```
<div class="ctema">...</div>
<hr />
<div class="ctema">...</div>
<hr />
<div class="ctema">...</div>
<hr />
```

But with a jquery script to fetch content via AJAX... the following pages have only:

```
<div class="ctema">...</div>
<div class="ctema">...</div>
<div class="ctema">...</div>
```

My goal is to have a HR tag between every div with class="ctema"... I tried this:

```
$('.ctematicas').before('<hr />');
```

But this doesn't checks if the HR tag is already there or not and after 5 dynamic reloads in the first page I end up with 5 HR in a row ...

How can I check if the HR tag is present between classes CTEMA and add one if not present?

Edited: Question clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
$('.ctema').not('hr+.ctema').before('<hr />');
```

or

```
$('.ctema:not(hr+.ctema)').before('<hr />');
```

jQuery's documentation suggests​​​​​​​ to prefer the first solution.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/wb6E6/)

---

If what you really want is to have one hr **between** the div (and not before the first one), then the solution is even simpler :

```
$('.ctema+.ctema').before('<hr />');​
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/jC7LS/)

Comment: You're missing a dot before the not.

Comment: "dot before the not" lol. It just sounded really funny when I read it in my head.

Comment: @VisioN the '+' combinator (or how those things are called) selects the second operand : *(“prev + next”) Selects all next elements matching "next" that are immediately preceded by a sibling "prev".*

Comment: @dystroy Right, thanks! However, seems that the OP wants `<hr>`s to be after blocks but not before.

Comment: @VisioN Question is a little unclear on this point. I added a solution to put hr between the divs, which seems the most interesting.

Comment: First page has 10 results all with hr between ... for the next 30 or so pages each loads 10 results and none has the hr tag... I want them all to have one and only one hr tag in between! Trying your suggestions now!

Comment: @dystroy: your solution worked like a charm! Accepted and VoteUp. Final code on my page: onRenderComplete: function(){$('.ctematicas:not(hr+.ctematicas)').before('<hr />');} [I'm using jquery.ias for infinite scrolling ... fantastic plugin btw)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I check if the HR tag is present between classes CTEMA and add
>   one if not present?

Not sure I get this, but I would probably do :

```
$('.ctema').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).next('hr').length
}).after('<hr>');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/u2Daz/)